# Verification registration by email using laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi everyone on this day I am designing my website and any new user must register on that and I used email to verification from them.
I am using laravel on my website I want to use the real email to send verification code for the new users I don't want a `mail-trap` service I want the real email. please tell me what I need to complete this job.
Remember that I want to do this when my website on free hosting, not real hosting.

Comment: There is a really nice website to have a look at for these situations: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the email through the event or in the same controller. My solution has been tested on **Laravel 5.6**. First of all, make the email settings for **gmail** in the `.env` file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=real email
MAIL_PASSWORD=real password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Suppose you want the users to have to activate their account after registration. So create a new model:

```
php artisan make:modal VerifyUser –m
```

Add this code to created `migration`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('verify_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('token')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then add `verified` field to the users table:

```
$table->boolean('verified')->default(false);
```

Then:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Add this method to `User Model`:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{    
    public function verifyUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\VerifyUser');
    }
}
```

Add this method to `VerifyUser Model`:

```
class VerifyUser extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Create a class for email that inherits from `Maiable`. This file is created in the email folder.

```
php artisan make:mail VerifyMail
```

Apply the following changes to `VerifyMail class`:

```
namespace App\Mail;
...
class VerifyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.verifyUser');
    }
}
```

Create a folder named emails and make a blade file named verifyUser in it. And Put the following code in it:

```
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to the site {{$user['name']}}</h2>
    <br/>
    Your registered email-id is {{$user['email']}} , Please click on the below link to verify your email account
    <br/>
    <a href="{{url('user/verify', $user->verifyUser->token)}}">Verify Email</a>
</body>
```

Change `create` method in `RegisterController`:

```
use App\Mail\VerifyMail;
use App\VerifyUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'token' => sha1(time())
        ]);
        \Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

        return $user;
    }
```

With this method, after the user register, a record is added to the user table, but the verified value is currently false or zero. Now to prevent the user login in immediately after registration, add the following method to the `RegisterController`:

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify.');
}
```

Unverified user should not log in in any way. And you have to override `authenticated` method to successful user login. So add `authenticated` method into `LoginController`:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (!$user->verified) {
        auth()->logout();
        return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');
    }
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Add this code to `login.blade.php` to display the message above:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
@if (session('warning'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        {{ session('warning') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Next, define a route for the link you sent to the user's email:

```
Route::get('/user/verify/{token}', 'Auth\RegisterController@verifyUser');
```

Now it's time to activate the user. Therefore, the verified value must be set to true or one. Add the following method to `RegisterController`:

```
public function verifyUser($token)
{
    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->first();
    if(isset($verifyUser) ){
        $user = $verifyUser->user;
        if(!$user->verified) {
            $verifyUser->user->verified = 1;
            $verifyUser->user->save();
            $status = "Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.";
        } else {
            $status = "Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.";
        }
    } else {
        return redirect('/login')->with('warning', "Sorry your email cannot be identified.");
    }
    return redirect('/login')->with('status', $status);
}
```

Complete.